# shell command to get bibtex entry from arxiv number

Tags: python, bash, command-line, bibtex

I am currently using the following `curl` command to get bibliographic information for a scientific article from its digital object identifier (DOI) number:

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1901/jaba.1974.7-497a
```

I would like to be able to do something similar for [arxiv](http://www.arxiv.org) articles, i.e. send the articles arxiv number to some web service and get bibliographic information back. How would I go about doing this?

I am looking for a solution in bash, zsh, or python.

Comment: That looks like a Bash command, are you looking for Python solutions or did you just put the wrong tag?

Comment: Did you visit https://arxiv.org/help/api/index and look for bibliography support?

Comment: @tripleee I'm looking for command line shell (bash, zsh) or a python solution.

Comment: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/03/09/Bibtex-Entries-from-Arxiv-org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38367) from [sebastian-busch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5969/sebastian-busch):

> I've written a python script that returns the corresponding bib-entry
>   from an arxiv ID, you can find it on
>   http://www.thamnos.de/misc/look-up-bibliographical-information-from-an-arxiv-id/.
>   If you save it e.g. as `arxiv2bib.py`, you can call it as
>   `arxiv2bib.py 1234.5678` or as
>   `arxiv2bib.py http://arxiv.org/abs/1234.5678`.

---

Someone also made a PHP script that can do it.

[PHP to automatically create BibTeX entry from arXiv](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/8133254)

From answer in [how-to-cite-an-article-from-arxiv-using-bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3833/how-to-cite-an-article-from-arxiv-using-bibtex)